# Observer - Observable model around an email receiving logic

Tags: java, observable, observer-pattern, observers

I have an email receiving logic written (class name: `Mail_Receive_Logic`). This class downloads all my unread emails into a `messages` array.

I also have classes `EmailStatPrinter` and `EmailStatRecorder` classes. `EmailStatPrinter` has a `writeToConsole` method which prints the array onto screen. `EmailStatRecorder` has a `writeToFile` method which writes the array in a text file.

I want to implement this logic in an observer-observable manner.

```
public class Mail_Receive_Logic extends Observable{ 
public class EmailStatPrinter implements Observer{
public class EmailStatRecorder implements Observer{
```

My main method looks like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

    // observable
    Mail_Receive_Logic receiveMail = new Mail_Receive_Logic(usernameReceiving, passwordReceiving, fileReceivePath);

    // observer
    EmailStatPrinter writeToConsole = new EmailStatPrinter();
    EmailStatRecorder writeToFile = new EmailStatRecorder();

    receiveMail.addObserver(writeToConsole);
    receiveMail.addObserver(writeToFile);

    Thread receive = new Thread (new Runnable() {
        public void run() { 
            try {
                while (true) {
                    receiveMail.receive();  
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }); 

    receive.start();
```

How should I write the **update method** of each observer classes such that they take in messages array and print it on console and text file. i.e I want to know what to write in following code segment for each observer classes.

```
@Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Please also explain me that why is there 2 variables Observable o and Object arg?

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `Observable.notifyObservers()` and supply the `arg`. It can be anything you like. In your case I think you would want something like:

```
try {
    while (true) {
        receiveMail.receive();
        receiveMail.notifyObservers(messages);
    }
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
}
```

Then in your Observers you would receive the messages as:

```
@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    // The first arg is the thing you were observing (receiveMail in this case)
    // The second arg is the messages that was passed by the receiveMail instance
}
```

Comment: In my Mail_Receive_Logic class (i.e the class belongs to receiveMail object), I have wrote a line `notifyObservers(messages);`. Does it wrong? or do I have to write like you did in main class?

Comment: I think you want call `receiveMail.notifyObservers(messages)` right after `receiveMail.receive()` as I am assuming that's how you get your `messages` object, and thus that's where you will have visibility to pass the messages to your observers.